# Reset a foreach loop in PHP for multiple runs

Tags: php, foreach

I have a form with 9 dropdown boxes that need to be populated by the same query. I use a foreach loop to list the options but copying the code to the scond dropdown produces no options. I guess it's because the result has already cycled so finds nothing.

How can I reset the result ready for each loop? Or maybe there is a more efficient way to achieve this that someone might know.

This is the query:

```
$qry2 = "SELECT ride_id, name FROM tpf_rides WHERE park_id = $park_id ORDER BY name ASC";
        $res2 = $pdo->query($qry2);
```

and this is the loop I am using:

```
<select name="ride_id_image">
    <option value="">Select Ride</option>

<?php   foreach ($res2 as $row2) {
    printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>' . PHP_EOL, $row2['ride_id'], $row2['name'] );
 } ?>
    </select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a much more effective way to do this. Instead of running through the result set multiple times, write it to a string once, and then you can re-use that as often as you need to:

```
<?php   

$options = "";

foreach ($res2 as $row2) {
    $options .= sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>' . PHP_EOL, $row2['ride_id'], $row2['name'] );
 } 

 ?>
```

Now, whenever you want to print the options, you can just echo out your string:

```
<select name="ride_id_image">
    <option value="">Select Ride</option>
    <?php echo $options ?>    
    </select>
```

Comment: You're welcome; I'd recommend looking at @watcher's answer, too, though - it'll give you more options in how you deal with the data you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

On first run, copy the data from the result set into an array.  On each subsequent run, perform the `foreach` over the array instead of the result set.

Or, you could be smart and do like @andrewsi says.

Comment: My method works well when it's identical content; this will work better if you're checking the values - for example, if you want to pre-populate the list with a `selected` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Andrewsi's answer is the most efficient. But to answer what you are trying to accomplish, you can just get the array from the PDO:

```
$qry2 = "SELECT ride_id, name FROM tpf_rides WHERE park_id = $park_id ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = $pdo->query($qry2);
$res2 = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```