# Using MySQL results array more than once

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code in my page

```
    <?php
    $dbc = mysql_connect();
    $db = mysql_select_db();
    $results= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_teams");
?>
<div class="datagrid"><table>
<thead><tr><th>header</th><th>header</th><th>header</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="game1_team1"><option value="0">Choose Team 1</OPTION><?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {echo '<option value="'.$row['team_ID'].'">'. $row['team_name'].'</option>';}?></select>
</td>
<td>Vs.</td>
<td>
<select name="game1_team2"><option value="0">Choose Team 2</OPTION><?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {echo '<option value="'.$row['team_ID'].'">'. $row['team_name'].'</option>';}?></select>
</td>
</tr>
```

The code shows the names of football teams from the MySQL table in dropdown game1_team1 but not in game1_team2; it's as though I can't use the same query twice. How do I remedy this? I'd like to use the same values for 60 identical drop downs on the page.

Can I store the values into an array and resuse them in each dropdown?

Comment: Yes. That's possible.

Comment: I answered a very similar question a couple of weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261538/reset-a-foreach-loop-in-php-for-multiple-runs/18261597#18261597

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to XSS. Always use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting to HTML markup. And those `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, please switch to MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE: The `mysql_*` function family is deprecated!**

What does that mean? It means you should stop using it today. Old code **should** be updated as time and budget allow, but you should never, **EVER** write a new line of code that involves these functions

---

Another note: it is bad practice to use `SELECT *...` -- explicitly name the columns you are going to use in your query. That way, if the table structure changes, you can detect that because your query will fail, and react accordingly (in code). This is part of a broader concept known as defensive coding.

On to the problem at hand!

You can use PDO to fetch an array of results out of the database. You can then use that array as many times as you'd like!

```
// simple sample for connecting with PDO
$host="my.host.name"; // Host name
$username="my_user_name"; // username
$password="my password"; // password
$db_name="my_database_name"; // Database name
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $username, $password);

// actually do the query
$statement= $pdo->prepare('
        SELECT 
            time_ID,
            team_name 
        FROM 
            `tbl_teams` 

');
$statement->execute();
// get an array with all the results
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

After that, you can loop the array to make a set of options, or do anything else with the data. For example:

```
$options = array();
foreach ($results as $one_result){
 $options[] = '<option value="'.$one_result['team_ID'].'">'.$one_result['team_name'].'</option>';
}
print '<select name="someSelectElement">'.implode('', $options).'</select>';
```

**Documentation**

- Deprecation notice for `mysql_*`  functions - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
- PHP PDO - http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
- PHP `mysqli` - http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: +1 for the detail about PDO

Comment: -1 for getting way off topic about the PDO, the OP just wants an answer, not a lecture

Comment: @DevlshOne It is not a lecture, it is the answer to the question. Code written with `mysql_` is **broken code**. No educated, ethical professional can, in good conscience, advocate using broken and deprecated functions. An answer containing `mysql_`  is off topic. But you can get butthurt about it with your -1 -- it ain't hurting me at all. Judging by the code in your answer, you don't know any better anyway.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I thank you for updating me on the security issues. But this system is only going to be used my a handful of people, non are going to have an interest in hacking into it. I will leave it how it is as that's code that i am comfortable with, and understand, and will understand if i need to edit the code in the future. many thanks

Comment: It won't be broken unless the OP upgrades to a version of PHP without the `mysql_*` functions, which currently does not exist. PHP 5.5 is the official version that depreciated the functions, however I haven't heard and solid word on when they will be removed completely. I too suggest using `mysqli` or `PDO` but the world will not end if you use `mysql` functions. I'd say at this point it would be a waste of time to update old code...

Comment: Do I only need to change:
    $dbc = mysql_connect();
    $db = mysql_select_db();
    $results= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_teams");
To:
    $dbc = mysqli_connect();
    $db = mysqli_select_db();
    $results= mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_teams");

Comment: @MikeAshfield the PHP documentation site has great examples of what needs to change. All of those lines will need to change to OOP style code.

Comment: Yes, if you're interested in moving to `mysqli` procedural style, it is relatively painless. Here's an article about that, along with a tool to convert code (not sure how well it works!): https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi

Comment: @Jasper -- if you are writing *new* code, it doesn't matter that the `mysql_` functions are still **temporarily** available. It is a dead end road. Why would anyone want to invest time writing dead code? That's purposely choosing to write code with a technical deficit attached right off the bat; you're literally saying, "no one in the future will ever want this code". Those are the kind of decisions that will, 90% of the time, come back to haunt you (or the poor next guy). The best practice (and the most logical) is to adjust to deprecations as soon as you are aware of them.

Comment: Why are you breaking the `SoC` by printing HTML tags? Why not to use an alternate syntax to deal with template logic? Like `<?php foreach(...): ?> ...pure html here... <?php endforeach;?>` ?

Comment: @DaveJust Using alternative syntax does not create separation of concerns. SoC is a structural attribute and is entirely abstract in the context of this answer, and not even close to within scope. Simply put, we have no idea what he's doing on that front (probably nothing), so why guess? What if he's using Smarty? Then alternative PHP syntax would have not made sense at all. At any rate, templates can (and do) use the `print` construct --- it is exactly equivalent to using alternative syntax.

Comment: @Chris I won't argue about writing new code but spending time to "fix" code that functions seems like over optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Using [PDO](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) you can easily fetch your results into an array, besides, the [`mysql_*` functions are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO( ... );
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_teams");
    $stmt->execute();

    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<div class="datagrid">
<table>
<thead><tr><th>header</th><th>header</th><th>header</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="game1_team1">
    <option value="0">Choose Team 1</OPTION>
    <?php
    foreach($results as $team) {
        echo "<option value='{$team['team_ID']}'>{$team['team_name']}</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
</td>
<td>Vs.</td>
<td>
<select name="game1_team2">
    <option value="0">Choose Team 2</OPTION>
    <?php
    foreach($results as $team) {
        echo "<option value='{$team['team_ID']}'>{$team['team_name']}</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

However, for efficiency I'd do this:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO( ... );
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_teams");
    $stmt->execute();

    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $teamList = '';
    foreach($results as $team) {
        $teamList .= "<option value='{$team['team_ID']}'>{$team['team_name']}</option>";
    }
?>

...
<select name="game1_team1">
    <option value="0">Choose Team 1</OPTION>
    <?php echo $teamList; ?>
</select>
...
<select name="game1_team2">
    <option value="0">Choose Team 2</OPTION>
    <?php echo $teamList; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **MYSQLI_***

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('host','user','password','db_name');
$results= mysqli_query("SELECT `team_ID`,`team_name` FROM tbl_teams");
?>
<div class="datagrid">
<table>
<thead><tr><th>header</th><th>header</th><th>header</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="game1_team1">
<option value="">Choose Team 1</OPTION>
<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc ,$results)) { echo '<option value="'.$row1['team_ID'].'">'. $row1['team_name'].'</option>';} ?>

</select>
</td>
<td>Vs.</td>
<td>
<select name="game1_team2">
<option value="">Choose Team 2</OPTION>
<?php while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc ,$results)) {echo '<option value="'.$row2['team_ID'].'">'. $row2['team_name'].'</option>';}?>
</select>
</td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

it will work now.. :)